# Как можно ускорить запрос что бы поиск происходил не больше 2 секунд?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица товаров в которых лежит 25 миллионов позиций, и есть связанная таблицы с серийными номерами продуктов, в одних и тег же товаров может быть одинаковый серийный номер, а может и не быть вообще, тогда нужно сделать поиск по названию товара.
Сейчас сделан обычный SELECR с LEFT JOIN c параметром (WHERE title = "search" OR barcode = "Search")
но он отрабатывает > 12 секунд.
Как можно ускорить запрос что бы поиск происходил не больше  2 секунд ?

Comment: Могу предложить вариант `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE title="search" OR barcode="search")`

Comment: Он будет еще дольше отрабатывать

Comment: Не всегда. Стоит ещё посмотреть на ваши индексы. Поля по которым осуществляется поиск и джойны лучше проиндексировать

Comment: Да и плюс у нас в таблице серийных номеров идет связь с таблицей продукта по id, потому что в одного продукта может быть несколько серийных номеров.

Comment: через лефт джоин отработал 11,1 секунд, ваш вариант отработал 13,4

Comment: В студию - CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц и точный текст оптимизируемого запроса, а также его EXPLAIN.